# how to reset elements affected by a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that runs when a box is clicked that affects multiple other elements on the page (creates a slideshow from a group of divs). There are multiple boxes on the page and I need to reset the elements affected by the function back to normal whenever the box is clicked again. Is there an easier way to reset the elements affected by the jQuery, or basically run the function backwards vs. writing another function that undoes what the first function did?

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlego/zeLNG/21/).

Comment: There is no undo, or history option that I'm aware of - will probably require writing the reverse script.

Comment: ... however, if your change involves something that can be targeted using CSS, I suggest @RSG's answer below. At least, adding/removing classes (or even attributes) can be delegated to the browser's CSS handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do what you describe is to use CSS classes to encapsulate all of the changes you want to apply with JQuery.  Your first function uses `addClass` to apply the changes and then you can use `removeClass` to revert the changes.

Comment: or `.toggleClass()`, which basically takes care of, well, toggling for you.

Answer (score 3):

There's no **simple** way to *run the function backwards*, because you need to know how to apply the opposite effect. Let's say you apply some color, you would first need to save the current color to be able to revert it.

The best way is to write a function that undoes what the first function did. Besides you can customize the "undo" function (suppose you want to do a different animation when scaling down an image or so).

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no shortcut to this other than writing a custom function that does what you need.

Here's a [discussion](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/newbie-question-how-to-play-my-animation-in-reverse-upon-second-click) on the jQuery forum about this.

Answer (score 1):

Well just a supplementary comment about your jsfiddle -- in your click listeners you should avoid create so many jquery objects using over and over again:

`$(this)`

Instead, define it just once at the top of the function:

`var $this = $(this);`

It will help performance and is a best practice.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first use of jQuery and I am utilizing others' scripts. I will keep this in mind.